# Entity Framework LINQ Get all items part of another collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Get all the NWatchRelation records from the DBContext that overlap those in the relationsCollection.
The same Id, RelatedNodeId, and RelationType (enum: int) should be what's considered a match.

```
public class NWatchRelation : INWatchRelation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int NodeId { get; set; }
    public NWatchNode Node { get; set; }
    public int RelatedNodeId { get; set; }

    public NWatchNode RelatedNode { get; set; }
    public NWatch.NWatchRelationType RelationType { get; set; }
}

INWatchRelation[] relationsCollection = GetRelations();
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a LINQ join between these 2 collections.

```
var result = from a in db.NWatchRelations.AsEnumerable()
             join b in relationsCollection on a.RelatedNodeId equals b.RelatedNodeId
                                           && a.Id equals b.Id
                                           && a.RelationType equals b.RelationType 
             select a;
```

Comment: I don't think EF supports joins to inmemory collections.

Comment: Slap an `AsEnumerable()` on the `db.NWatchRelations` and it should work, though performance could be an issue.

Comment: Absolutely correct @IvanStoev. Thanks for pointing out. @juhaar. Thanks. updated to include `AsEnumberale` ( I was going to put `.ToList()`  :) )

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can do that fully in LINQ to Entities is to manually compose `UNION ALL` query by using [`Queryable.Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351755(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
IQueryable<NWatchRelation> query = null;
foreach (var relation in relationsCollection)
{
    var m = relation;
    var subQuery = db.NWatchRelations
        .Where(r => r.Id == m.Id
            && r.RelatedNodeId == m.RelatedNodeId
            && r.RelationType == m.RelationType);
    query = query == null ? subQuery : query.Concat(subQuery);
}
```

But please note that it's a limited approach and will not work if the `relationsCollection` is big.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a kind of unique key using the three values:

```
//To create a unique key (an string, which is a primitive type) combining the three values
var keys=relationsCollection.Select(e=>e.Id+"-"+e.RelatedNodeId+"-"+ ((int)e.RelationType)).Distinct();

var query=db.NWatchRelations.Where(r=>keys.Any(k=>k == (SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)r.Id)+"-"+
                                                        SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)r.RelatedNodeId )+"-"+ 
                                                        SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)((int)r.RelationType)) ));
```

If your `NWatchRelations` table doesn't have many rows or `relationsCollection` is a small collection, please,  use one of the alternatives that were proposed earlier at your convinience.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can have the directly linked like this

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public NWatchRelation()
    {
        this.INWatchRelation = new HashSet<INWatchRelation>();
    }
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<INWatchRelation> INWatchRelation { get; set; }
```

But the entiry relation must be liked like this in order to work properly

Then you could select/list it like this

```
db.NWatchRelation.INWatchRelation.ToList();
```