# Trying to combine 2 linq expressions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have some queries over an Entity Framework model and am trying to be clever about consolidating my queries.

I already have a generic repository.

Here's the crux of what I'm trying to do - it doesn't work but I'm not sure why and how to fix it.

The second function in code works but there are a couple of issues in the first - I've included it so that you can get the gist of what I'm trying to do.

```
    IEnumerable<Product> QueryLive(Expression<Func<Product, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var exp = new Expression<Func<Product, bool>>(x => x.IsLive);

        var combined = Expression.AndAlso(exp, predicate);

        return QueryPublished(combined);
    }

    IEnumerable<Product> QueryPublished(Expression<Func<Product, bool>> predicate)
    {
        using (var uow = new UnitOfWork(Connections.ProductComparision))
        {
            var r = new Repository<Product>(uow.Context);

            return r.Find(predicate).ToList();
        }
    }
```

I get 2 syntax errors:

Line: var exp = 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Return: 'combined' var is a binary expression and conflicts with the param requirements of QueryPublished().

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Does this code compile?

Comment: @AndersonPimentel - added errors to post.

Comment: @YacoubMassad - No, please see updated post for errors.

Comment: You can't combine lambda expressions this way. You could use some predicate builder libraries, for instance [universal PredicateBuilder](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/)

Comment: @IvanStoev - nothing built in then?

Comment: Nothing built in. But it's a simple class with few methods. I have one too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36514355/applying-linq-filters-based-on-a-multi-dimensional-array/36515245#36515245 :)

Comment: @IvanStoev - I've gone withyour answer as it provides a robust solution. If you create an answer pointing to the other answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some issues that I see with your code:

- `var exp = new Expression<Func<Product, bool>>(x => x.IsLive);` will not compile, to define an expression, simple use the following syntax:

  `Expression<Func<Product, bool>> exp = x => x.IsLive;`
- `combined` is of type `Expression` and `QueryPublished` is expecting an argument of type `Expression<Func<Product, bool>>`. This wouldn't compile also.
- The parameter in `predicate` (e.g. the `x` in `x =>`) is different than the lambda parameter `exp`, so you can't simply combine them this way.

You can use [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) to combine expressions easily like this:

```
IEnumerable<Product> QueryLive(Expression<Func<Product, bool>> predicate)
{
    Expression<Func<Product, bool>> exp = x => x.IsLive;

    Expression<Func<Product, bool>> combined = x => exp.Invoke(x) && predicate.Invoke(x);

    return QueryPublished(combined.Expand());
}
```

Comment: `Invoke` is not really needed because LinqKit includes a PredicateBuilder with `And` / `Or` extension methods (as you know :)

Comment: @IvanStoev, actually I never knew about the `PredicateBuilder` in LinqKit before. Thanks for letting me know. Can it be used in this case if the parameters in the two expressions are different?

Comment: It still has to be combined with `Expand` / `AsExpandable`.

Answer (score 0):

**First**:

Change

```
var exp = new Expression<Func<Product, bool>>(x => x.IsLive);
```

To

```
Expression<Func<Product, bool>> exp = x => x.IsLive;
```

**Second**:

Change

```
var combined = Expression.AndAlso(exp, predicate);
```

To

```
var combined = Expression.Lambda<Func<Product, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(exp.Body, predicate.Body), exp.Parameters);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work because the 2 expression bodies are bound to a different parameter.

Comment: I'm not sute if the output is correct for this but ir does compile.

Comment: I have a very similar code working in one my projects. In fact, in my code I combine the parameters from the two expressions before using them: `left.Parameters.Concat(right.Parameters).GroupBy(p => p.Name).Select(g => g.First())`

Comment: @JohnOhara In LINQ to Entities (and in general with expressions, reflection etc) compile doesn't mean works :)

Comment: Never used LINQ to Entities. It works fine with NHibernate. To be honest, one little thing must be changed: `exp = x => x.IsLive` should be `exp = x => x.IsLive == true`. NH tends to be kinda lost with simple boolean expressions. =)

Comment: @IvanStoev Just tested here: works fine with NHibernate, but does not with Linq To Objects. I think NH LINQ Provider only cares about the parameter name.

Comment: EF does care, trust me :) To make it work, you need a simple parameter replacer.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the [`Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) class methods are for building the expression trees (e.g. the lambda expression [`Body`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.body(v=vs.110).aspx) and cannot be used directly for combining lambda expressions.

For combining the so called predicate expressions (`Expression<Func<T, bool>>`) as in your case, one usually would use some custom helper extension methods, called predicate builders. The most famous is the `PredicateBuilder` from [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx), but it's not compatible with EF and requires `Expand` / AsExpandable` services from the package. I personally use my own, posted here [Applying LINQ filters based on a multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36514355/applying-linq-filters-based-on-a-multi-dimensional-array/36515245#36515245) and [Establish a link between two lists in linq to entities where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246162/establish-a-link-between-two-lists-in-linq-to-entities-where-clause/36247259#36247259), which as been pointed in comments by [Gert Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861716/gert-arnold) is very similar to the [universal PredicateBuilder](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/). Both produce EF compatible expressions, here is mine:

```
public static class PredicateUtils
{
    sealed class Predicate<T>
    {
        public static readonly Expression<Func<T, bool>> True = item => true;
        public static readonly Expression<Func<T, bool>> False = item => false;
    }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Null<T>() { return null; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return Predicate<T>.True; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return Predicate<T>.False; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> left, Expression<Func<T, bool>> right)
    {
        if (Equals(left, right)) return left;
        if (left == null || Equals(left, True<T>())) return right;
        if (right == null || Equals(right, True<T>())) return left;
        if (Equals(left, False<T>()) || Equals(right, False<T>())) return False<T>();
        var body = Expression.AndAlso(left.Body, right.Body.Replace(right.Parameters[0], left.Parameters[0]));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, left.Parameters);
    }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> left, Expression<Func<T, bool>> right)
    {
        if (Equals(left, right)) return left;
        if (left == null || Equals(left, False<T>())) return right;
        if (right == null || Equals(right, False<T>())) return left;
        if (Equals(left, True<T>()) || Equals(right, True<T>())) return True<T>();
        var body = Expression.OrElse(left.Body, right.Body.Replace(right.Parameters[0], left.Parameters[0]));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, left.Parameters);
    }

    static Expression Replace(this Expression expression, Expression source, Expression target)
    {
        return new ExpressionReplacer { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expression);
    }

    class ExpressionReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public Expression Source;
        public Expression Target;
        public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
        {
            return node == Source ? Target : base.Visit(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have such helpers, the method in question is simple as that:

```
IEnumerable<Product> QueryLive(Expression<Func<Product, bool>> predicate)
{
    return QueryPublished(predicate.And(x => x.IsLive));
}
```